# Two Way (Double) Binding in Angular Model Driven Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Here's an interface:

`interface User { name: string; }`

and a reactive form:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
    name: [user.name, Validators.required]
  });
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" novalidate>
  <input type="text" formControlName="name">
</form>
```

Is there a way to have the value of `user.name` get updated automatically (two-way binding just like template-driven `ngModel`) when the `input` field gets updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible.

At first you need to import the `FormsModule` next to the `ReactiveFromsModule` to your project.

And add `[(ngModel)]="name"` to your html, it looks like following:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" formControlName="test">
</form>
```

See this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/JdQ5ogyALNXEbAV79Kw0?p=preview).

**Update model via subscription:**
You can subscribe to the formGroup valueChange and edit your model respectively.

Like this way:

```
  this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe((changes) => {
    this.submitObj = changes;

    for(let propName in changes){
      this.test[propName] = changes[propName];
    }
  })
```

Comment: Oh wow, so it's not inherently supported by Reactive Forms :-(

Comment: I have extended my answer and update my plunkr sample. I hope that will help =)

Comment: Ok. So I assume what you're calling *full reactive way* is the alternative?